# VSE: Select next or previous strip with the keyboard

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, shortcut

After starting using Blender VSE for a while, I would like to get free of the mouse for selecting strips on the timeline.

Let A be a strip and B another strip following A on the channel (with or without empty space):

```
[   A   ]    [     B     ]
```

Is there a shortcut to select B when the current strip is A? Or to select A when the current one is B?

In many GUI apps selecting a contiguous item is done with TAB and Shift-TAB.

If that can't be done with built-in keymaps operators, can you address me to the relevant API section to try and write a Python script?